# Lost the ability to select/highlight text in Adobe Reader 9

Tags: adobe-reader

I have lost the ability to select/highlight text in Adobe Reader 9 in Win 7 and it's not because of document security settings because I can do it on my Ubuntu side.  How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be document security settings, Evince (default on Ubuntu) are able to cross some security setting (no printing, etc).